# Jquery ajax response put json elements into array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm running a python script with ajax and trying to interpret the result.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyxZt/4/) is a great start as my json looks exactly like this.

```
var j ='[{"id":"1","name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"},{"id":"3","name":"test3"},{"id":"4","name":"test4"},{"id":"5","name":"test5"}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
       // console.log(k+" : "+ v);       
        $('#cand').append('<p>'+k+' : '+ v+'</p>');
});
});
```

Result:

```
id : 1
name : test1
id : 2
name : test2
id : 3
name : test3
id : 4
name : test4
id : 5
name : test5
```

How do I fill an array with this data? I would like this result:

```
1 test1
2 test2
3 test3
4 test4
5 test5
```

(and let's suppose there might be more columns, just stick to these 2 for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to have the inner loop. Iterate array, then output the object properties you want

```
$(json).each(function(i,item){
    $('#cand').append('<p>'+item.id+' : '+ item.name+'</p>');   
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fyxZt/1735/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! This is the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to store values of properties of each array value and log that variable at the end of the first loop.

```js
var j = '[{"id":"1","name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"},{"id":"3","name":"test3"},{"id":"4","name":"test4"},{"id":"5","name":"test5"}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);
$(json).each(function(i, val) {
  var result = '';
  $.each(val, function(k, v) {
    result += v + " ";
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An array with two columns from your json:

```
var myArray = [];
var json = $.parseJSON(j);
$(json).each(function(){
    myArray[myArray.length] = [this.id, this.name];
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fyxZt/1736/)

Answer (score 0):

Though all the above solutions work, I found an even better one:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response);
var columns = new Array()
for (var i=0; i<json.length; ++i) {
    columns[i] = new Array(json[i].id, json[i].name, json[i].age);
}
```